# How can I implement simple distributed processing in a Unity game?

Tags: unity, networking

I'm looking to set up a game which uses distributed processing. Just a simple brick shooter in unity with the distributed part being that the calculations for the falling blocks are handled by another PC and the transformations are sent back and applied to a clients machine.

To use this in Unity I assume I'll be using Remote Procedure Calls?
Will I also require socket programming? Any other networking elements I require?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the requirements of your game, you'll only need to use [RPC calls](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/net-RPCDetails.html). That will require a [NetworkView](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-NetworkView.html) component (which you can set Observed to None, and State Synchronization to Off).